# using icons from a vector icon image

Tags: html, css, vector, icons

Their are a lot of icon images available on internet. I just downloaded [this](http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/047/d/0/350_free_vector_web_icons_by_themecavern-d4pwo03.jpg) one and 
the problem is i don't know how to use it, i am searching for some tutorials on this topic but can't find some useful stuff.
Anyone here who know how to use these icons ?

Comment: You haven't explained *how* you want to use the images. In a WinForms application toolbar? In a website? In an iOS app?

Comment: Did you by any chance download the .jpg file you linked to? In that case it's the wrong file...

Comment: Wherever you downloaded this image, there was probably a link to download (or purchase and then download ;) ) this icon pack as a zip of individual images... But in case this question is really about `sprites` - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about using a `sprite` image for icons (although the image you shown is not a good example of how to make a sprite... ;)

Then, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/sWZrh/

Basically, you set one `background-image` to all your icons-to-be, and then just reposition it with `background-position`

Comment: How do you know the positions? trial and error? is it hardcoded per platform?

Comment: @daveL the sprite is essentially an image (one huge image containing a lot of icons). If You're the one creating it - You know the positions where the icons really are. If You're reusing someone else`s sprite, then You will have to open it and measure the positions. But it is not platform-dependent.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there a handy tool for measuring positions?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the authors of the icons will provide you with instructions. How to use the icons depends on their format. The most common way to provide icons these days seem to be as web fonts. A good example is [symbolset](http://symbolset.com/).

If you only have the vectors, for instance in .ai or .eps format, you can use a vector editor such as Adobe Illustrator to export it to SVG. Sadly support for SVG is not as good as it is for webfonts. A better option might be to make the webfont yourself. There are several options available, I have had success with the application [Glyphs](http://glyphsapp.com/), but it can be time-consuming.

If you end up with a webfont, you first need to include the font, and set the target element to use it. Then insert an icon by referencing the correct character. If the result is an SVG image you can insert it with the *img* tag.